# Firefox Developer Edition Dropdown

Tags: html, firefox, input

Bit of a weird one. Firefox developer edition seems to be rendering options in an HTML5  input in font Times New Roman, instead of browser default font. Unless this is Firefox Developer Edition Default font, but I’d find that hard to believe.

On Chrome or regular Firefox, Times New Roman is nowhere to be seen. Any ideas?

Can provide screenshots if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered through research: Firefox Developer edition defaults to Times New Roman when custom font is applied to  element. Got around this by using browser standardised font, Helvetica. Does not seem to be a reliable way to restyle font of options within a select item, and when one is hovered over.